# Move top link navigation below in sharepoint 2019 online

Tags: sharepoint-2019

I'm trying to move the top link navigation bar as shown on the below image.

[image]

`Corporate Info` & `Finance` are sub-sites that are displayed in the top nav and need to move them below as shown. Is there anyway this can be achieved?

Comment: You have tagged your question with `sharepoint-2013`, `sharepoint-online`, and `sharepoint-2019`.  Those are actually three completely different versions of SharePoint.  Which one are you asking about?

Comment: willman is totally correct which version you are asking about, because to handle that you should handle it through css, and the css selector is different from version to another, also css selector could be different between browsers, so to do that you need to specify which version you are targeting.

Comment: @willman - SharePoint 2019